# basic handwriting app issue (not recognition)

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

trying to toy around with android studio for a bit, had some inspiration. i tried looking up online and tried ChatGPT but i cant get this to work - what i'm trying to do for now is to show basic handwriting on the screen. the screen is purple colored intentionally so i can see the area im allowed to write in.

im new to this so i cant be too sure about any issues yet. would love if someone could point me in the right direction!

MainActivity.kt:

```
package com.example.myapplication

import HandWritingView.HandwritingView
import android.content.ContentValues
import android.graphics.Bitmap
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.Environment
import android.provider.MediaStore
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private var handwritingView: HandwritingView? = null
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        handwritingView = findViewById<HandwritingView>(R.id.handwriting_view)

        val saveButton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.save_button)

        saveButton.setOnClickListener {
            val bitmap = handwritingView?.getBitmap()

            // Save the bitmap as a file in the device's external storage
            val contentValues = ContentValues().apply {
                put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, "handwriting_${System.currentTimeMillis()}.jpg")
                put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg")
                put(MediaStore.Images.Media.RELATIVE_PATH, Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
            }
            val resolver = applicationContext.contentResolver
            val uri = resolver.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, contentValues)
            uri?.let {
                resolver.openOutputStream(uri).use { outputStream ->
                    if (bitmap?.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outputStream) == false)  {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to save image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    }
                }
                Toast.makeText(this, "Image saved successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
    }

}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Handwrite something and click the 'Save' button to save the image to your device's gallery."
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/save_button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <HandWritingView.HandwritingView
        android:id="@+id/handwriting_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@color/purple_700"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/save_button"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/save_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
        android:text="Save"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

HandwritingView.kt:

```
package HandWritingView

import android.content.Context
import android.graphics.*
import android.util.AttributeSet
import android.view.MotionEvent
import android.view.View

class HandwritingView(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?) : View(context, attrs) {

    private val paint = Paint().apply {
        color = Color.BLACK
        style = Paint.Style.STROKE
        strokeWidth = 12f
        isAntiAlias = true
        isDither = true
    }
    private var path = Bitmap.createBitmap(1, 1, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
    private var canvas = Canvas(path)
    private var lastX = 0f
    private var lastY = 0f

    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas)
        canvas.drawBitmap(path, null, RectF(0f, 0f, width.toFloat(), height.toFloat()), null)
    }


    override fun onTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        val x = event.x
        val y = event.y
        when (event.action) {
            MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
                lastX = x
                lastY = y
                performClick() // Call performClick on ACTION_DOWN event
                return true
            }
            MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE -> {
                canvas.drawLine(lastX, lastY, x, y, paint)
                lastX = x
                lastY = y
                invalidate()
                return true
            }
            MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {
                canvas.drawLine(lastX, lastY, x, y, paint)
                invalidate()
                return true
            }
        }
        return super.onTouchEvent(event)
    }


    override fun performClick(): Boolean {
        super.performClick()
        // Your code here, if any
        return true
    }

    fun clear() {
        path = Bitmap.createBitmap(1, 1, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
        canvas = Canvas(path)
        invalidate()
    }

    fun getBitmap(): Bitmap {
        return path
    }
}
```

like i said im new to this topic so please dont be too harsh on me if it's inappropriate in anyway. i was lost trying to learn and thought praticing this way is the best way. really sorry if this is the case!

I'm adding my file layout, just in case:

[image: files layout]

all i was trying to do is a simple handwriting app and show in black the handwriting.
on the emulator i don't even see the purple area at all.
on my physical device(s) i do see it, but cant see any handwriting done, by finger or pen.
im not sure how come those are different (guessing android version? maybe?) and why the handwriting isn't shown.

any help would be much appreciated!!! ty :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your View isn't too far off, but it isn't quite right either. Use a Path object.  Accumulate all the move touch events into the Path using lineTo.  Draw the path in onDraw.  No need to have a Bitmap at all.

Comment: put your answer into gpt, it generated the code and now it works! studying it now. tyvm!!